# What does >> mean in C++ code?

Tags: c++, bit

`static CBigNum bnProofOfWorkLimit(~uint256(0) >> 32);`

That statement is filled with all sorts of magic. What exactly is it doing?

Comment: What is `uint256`? I've not seen such type. If it is a class-type, then `>>` could mean anything, as the author of the class meant it. Also, in that case, the meaning of `~` also depends on the type.

Comment: A lot of downvoting for a question that got so many answers. Why?

Comment: Questions get downvoted because of the questions themselves, their quality, not because of lack of answers. A really bad question often gets really good answers, and for which there are even badges!

Comment: What's lacking in quality of my question?

Comment: wth are `uint256`,  `bnProofOfWorkLimit`, and `CBigNUM` ???

Comment: @walter its from the Bitcoin code. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.1.5/main.h#L22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does >> mean in C++ code?

For integer types, it's the *binary right-shift* operator, which takes the binary representation of its first operand, and moves it a number of places to the right. `a >> b` is roughly the same as `a / pow(2,b)`.

> That statement is filled with all sorts of magic. What exactly is it doing?

`uint256` isn't a standard type or function; I'll assume it's a big-number type with 256 bits, with suitable operator overloads so that it acts like a standard numeric type. So `uint256(0)` is a 256-bit number with value zero.

`~` is the binary negation operator; it zeros all set bits, and sets all zero bits. So `~uint256(0)` will contain 256 bits, all set.

Finally, the shift moves those bits 32 bits to the right. So the top 32 bits will all be zero, and the remaining 224 bits will be set.

Comment: So the end result will be something like `00001111111`? Where there are 32 0's and 220 1's?

Comment: @Shamoon: Yes, just like that.

Comment: +1. This is an answer that covers other possible meanings.

Comment: @MikeSeymour 256-32 != 220

Answer (score 4):

Assuming uint256 is a 256 bit unsigned integer type and the operators are defined as for the built-in types, this will:

- initialize a 256 bit unsigned integer with 0
- bitwise invert it (operator ~)
- right-shift it by 32 bits (operator >>)

See [Wikipedia on C / C++ operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)

Comment: Why would someone invert and shift it?

Comment: Inverting 0 gives you uint256_MAX (whose representation is all 1's), and right-shifting that by 32 gives you an integer of the form 00000..0001111...111

Answer (score 3):

My guess is a shift. It's shifting the bits to the right, possibly by 32 bits. We can't say for sure without seeing the uint256 class due to c++ operator overloading.

Comment: Please don't *guess* without knowing the type. Or write all possible meanings that it could have.